# How to replace string with variable in Twig

Tags: php, html, symfony, twig

```
{% image '@AppBundle/Resources/public/images/florida.png'%}
    <img src="{{ asset_url }}" alt="Example" height="200" width="200"/>
{% endimage %}
```

I have this code here from my twig file. I want to load an image called "florida.png from the file location:"@AppBundle/Resources/public/images/florida.png". I want to replace the "@AppBundle/Resources/public/images/florida.png" with a string variable and was wondering how I could do this? Any help would be of great assistance!

Comment: Have you tried the common twig way of assigning? `{% set some_var = asset_url %}`

Comment: im very new to twig, I was wondering if you could show me an example of this please?

Comment: Twig docs provide quite a lot of examples http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/set.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but could you please show me how it would work in my code! I was wondering if you could rewrite the same snippet instead of '@AppBundle/Resources/public/images/florida.png'. I need a variable. Thanks

Comment: Can you please show me how it would look like in my example? Thanks

Comment: This is not a code-writing service.  Read the docs and make an attempt first.

Comment: My problem is that every time i replace '@AppBundle/Resources/public/images/florida.png' for example for {{ temp }} I get an error saying Unexpected token "punctuation" of value "{"

Comment: Jack, why dont you just use `<img src="{{ path_to_file }}" />` and be done with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're after?

```html
<img src="{{ asset('bundles/app/images/florida.png') }}" alt="Example" height="200" width="200"/>
```